# Get actual contents of Git commits (diffs) using Azure Devops API

Tags: git, azure-devops, tfs

I am listing git commits in an azure devops git repository to check if any commits breaks some simple principles.

However, it seems like GitItem.Content and GitChange.NewContent both are null.

They are never populated by my code so I cannot get the actual changes.

The following code is not outputting anything.

How can I get change content?

Also, am I doing anything in an overly complicated way? (My code results in a lot of API calls).

```cs
    private void GetGitChanges()
    {
      var organization = "org";
      var project = "proj";
      var repositoryId = "repo";

      var uri = $"https://tfs.foobar.se/tfs/{organization}/";
      var pat = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PAT"];
      using (var conn = new VssConnection(new Uri(uri), new VssBasicCredential("", pat)))
      {
        var gitClient = conn.GetClient<GitHttpClient>();
        var repo = gitClient.GetRepositoryAsync(project, repositoryId).WaitForResult();
        var gitCommits = new List<GitCommitRef>();

        var searchCriteria = new GitQueryCommitsCriteria
        {
          IncludeWorkItems = true,
          ItemVersion = new GitVersionDescriptor
          {
            VersionType = GitVersionType.Branch,
            VersionOptions = GitVersionOptions.FirstParent,
            Version = "master"
          }
        };

        var commits = gitClient.GetCommitsAsync(project, repo.Id.ToString(), searchCriteria).WaitForResult();

        foreach(var commit in commits)
        {
          var c2 = gitClient.GetCommitAsync(project: project, commitId: commit.CommitId, repositoryId: repositoryId)
              .WaitForResult();
          if (c2.Parents?.Any() ?? false)
          {
            var parentCommitId = c2.Parents.First();

            var diff = gitClient.GetCommitDiffsAsync(repositoryId: repositoryId, project: project, diffCommonCommit: false,
                targetVersionDescriptor: new GitTargetVersionDescriptor { Version = commit.CommitId, VersionType = GitVersionType.Commit, VersionOptions = GitVersionOptions.None }, 
                baseVersionDescriptor: new GitBaseVersionDescriptor { Version = parentCommitId, VersionType = GitVersionType.Commit, VersionOptions = GitVersionOptions.None }).WaitForResult();

            foreach(var change in diff.Changes)
            {
              if (change.Item.Content != null)
              {
                Debug.WriteLine(change.Item.Content);
              }
              if (change.NewContent != null)
              {
                Debug.WriteLine(change.NewContent);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

## edit

ChatGPT suggests that I should pass the parameter `includeContent: true` to `GetCommitDiffsAsync`, but there is no such parameter (or any parameter that looks like it)